# PhpMyAdmin - SQL Creating tables Error #1064

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I'm trying to create some tables, with a one-to-many relationship between them. I get this error, I have read other threads, and suspect it is something to do with the FK. Any help would be great! :D Thanks

I'm using PhpMyAdmin on a XAMPP server. I created the database, clicked SQL tab, and put my code it. I got the error below.

**Error:**

```
Error
Static analysis:

2 errors were found during analysis.

Unexpected beginning of statement. (near "userID" at position 307)
Unrecognized statement type. (near "INT" at position 314)
SQL query:

CREATE TABLE reportTable ( reportID INT AUTO_INCREMENT, submitDate DATETIME, submitBy VARCHAR(255), reportInformation VARCHAR(255), reviewedBy VARCHAR(255), PRIMARY KEY(reportID), FOREIGN KEY(userID) REFERENCES userTable(userID) ) CREATE TABLE userTable ( userID INT AUTO_INCREMENT, username VARCHAR(255), PRIMARY KEY(userID) )

MySQL said: Documentation

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'CREATE TABLE userTable (
    userID INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
    username VARCHAR(2' at line 11
```

**Code:**

```
CREATE TABLE reportTable (
    reportID INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
    userID INT,
    submitDate DATE,
    submitBy VARCHAR(255),
    reportInformation VARCHAR(255),
    reviewedBy VARCHAR(255),
    PRIMARY KEY(reportID),
    FOREIGN KEY(userID) REFERENCES userTable(userID)
);

CREATE TABLE userTable (
    userID INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
    username VARCHAR(255),
    PRIMARY KEY(userID)
);
```

Comment: Semi-colons end your statements. Otherwise, it's a run-on sentence.

Comment: @aynber Should i add semi-colons where?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned in my comment, semi-colons are usually used to end statements. Otherwise, MySQL doesn't know when you mean to stop. When doing one query in PHPMyAdmin, it will interpret it properly, but not when you do more than one statement. This will fix your run-on statements.

```
CREATE TABLE reportTable (
    reportID INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
    submitDate DATE,
    submitBy VARCHAR(255),
    reportInformation VARCHAR(255),
    reviewedBy VARCHAR(255),
    PRIMARY KEY(reportID),
    FOREIGN KEY(userID) REFERENCES userTable(userID)
);

CREATE TABLE userTable (
    userID INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
    username VARCHAR(255),
    PRIMARY KEY(userID)
);
```

Comment: Ahh, I see. Thank you! I will mark as asnwered when it lets me. Another error has popped up though. #1005 - Can't create table `mcreport`.`reporttable` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed") (Details…)

Comment: You don't actually have a userID field in your reportTable.

Comment: I then get this error: #1072 - Key column 'userID' doesn't exist in table @aynber

Comment: Right. Add `userID INT` into your reportTable columns.